# Did Mon Mothma know who Leia's parents were?

Tags: star-wars

Prior to the events in *Bloodline*, did Mon Mothma know who Leia's family really were? We see multiple times in the Clone Wars show Mon Mothma working with Padmé (and sometimes Anakin), and was close friends with Bail, so did she know?

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/145427/51379

Answer (score 9):

### She probably already knew about Padmé

In her follow-up speech to the Senate, Leia mentions that her birth mother had been known for some time:

> As many have known for a long time, and as you heard on the recording yesterday, my birth mother was also well known. Padmé Amidala Naberrie served the planet of Naboo first as queen, then as senator.
>
> <sup>*Bloodline* Chapter 25</sup>

Leia herself had learned it some years before this:

> Leia couldn't relax. She found herself thinking of her mother — the birth mother she hadn't known, Padmé Amidala. After Leia had learned her mother's identity years ago, she'd done what research she could to discover something more about the former queen and senator.
>
> <sup>*Bloodline* Chapter 9</sup>

So it seems likely that Mothma also knew this.

### She suspected about Vader

This is mentioned in Mon Mothma's message of support to Leia following the public reveal:

> Mon Mothma's message even hinted that she'd suspected for a long while — which meant she'd never allowed it to prejudice their relationship.
>
> <sup>*Bloodline* Chapter 28</sup>

### She probably knew about Anakin, but it's not clear

It seems likely that she'd have known, since Luke had been told by Owen and Beru that his father was named Anakin Skywalker, and by the time of *Bloodline* everybody knows that Luke and Leia are related; it doesn't seem like any great secret by this point.

Luke himself certainly isn't shy about mentioning that his father was a Jedi who fought in the Clone Wars; he rather off-handedly admits this, to a person he's known for barely a day, no less, in the novel *Heir to the Jedi* (which, admittedly, is set before *Empire Strikes Back*):

> [The speaker's uncle] used to talk about another Jedi who could fly like no other, and his name also happened to be Skywalker. That's why that fleeting glimpse of a lightsaber piqued my interest. I don't suppose you had any
>   relatives among the Jedi?"
>
> [Luke's] heart pumped faster. "Yes. My father was a Jedi who fought in the Clone Wars."
>
> <sup>*Heir to the Jedi* Chapter 2</sup>

And Yupe Tashu, a member of the Imperial Ruling Council, mentions the fact quite casually in a conversation with Imperial bigwigs in *Aftermath*:

> "No Sith remain," Tashu says. "And the lone Jedi that exists — the son of Anakin Skywalker — possesses an untouchable soul.
>
> <sup>*Aftermath* Chapter 15</sup>

So it seems plausible that she'd have heard it somewhere, or else just put the pieces together herself.

Comment: I think as soon as it was public knowledge that Leia and Luke Skywalker were siblings that Mon would put two-and-two together. That's assuming they didn't publicly acknowledge Anakin was Luke's father, which realistically speaking they most likely did. The only secret here is that he was also Darth Vader. I can see how Mon might suspect given the timing of Padme's death, the sudden appearance of Vader at Palpatine's side and how close Anakin was to him when he was Chancellor. It's also possible Bail may have said something that indirectly tipped Mon off.