# Was anyone else watching Leia as she grew up?

Tags: star-wars, princess-leia

In the aftermath of Order 66, there is a small group of remaining Jedi and senators who know the truth about who Luke and Leia are and why they must be protected.  Yoda leaves in exile to Dagobah, but Obi-Wan and Bail make the decision as to where to place the twins.  Obi-Wan takes Luke to Tatooine to live with his family, but Obi-Wan stays there to keep himself hidden and also watch over Luke as he grows up.  Bail, on the other hand, seems to be on his own on Alderaan - this answer ([Did Bail Organa tell his wife about Leia's parentage?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/145427/did-bail-organa-tell-his-wife-about-leias-parentage)) seems to imply that Bail didn't even tell his wife the truth about Leia's parentage, since he said in a recording from Bloodline that he wanted to tell Leia this himself.

There was the possibility that Leia would be Force-sensitive, the same as Luke, and that she would be in danger because of who she was.  While it is perfectly plausible that Bail's status would give Leia sufficient protection, which is why Obi-Wan left to watch over Luke, it made me wonder - was there anyone else watching over Leia?

It makes sense if there wasn't anyone else, and because the number of people left who knew about Luke and Leia was few, but I am wondering if there was someone else who was watching over Leia as she grew up on Alderaan.

Comment: And, in fact, she was Force-sensitive.

Comment: I am unsure how any senators would know of Luke and Leia since only Obi-Wan, Bail and Yoda were there when Padma gave birth.

Comment: Another good question is why they didn’t change Luke’s last name to “Lars” to hide him better. I suppose out in the galactic boonies there’s less need for that as opposed to on Alderaan.

Comment: I'm sure I read in a star wars book that there was actually some Jedi watching her; but not full time.

Comment: @ToddWilcox George Lucas once said, the name "Skywalker" is as common as for example "Smith" is here.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, sort of**

In the recent series Obi Wan Kenobi we see Leia getting kidnapped, so Bail calls out to Obi Wan for help who begrudgingly takes the job and saves Leia.

Now you can say he wasn't looking after her but he was continuously keeping tabs on her simultaneously as Luke and responded when she was in danger.

Description of Obi Wan Kenobi show -

> Obi-Wan Kenobi is a spin-off series based on the titular Jedi knight, whom we have earlier seen in both the Original Trilogy and the Prequel Trilogy. Ewan McGregor, who played the role in the prequels, returns to the universe after 17 years. The series is set 10 years after the events of Episode III: Revenge of the Sith and sees Obi-Wan hiding from the Galactic Empire and look after Luke and Leia. The first two episodes of the six-episode series released on Disney+

So the description does say he was looking after her.

[Source](https://www.hindustantimes.com/entertainment/web-series/obiwan-kenobi-star-wars-spin-off-rightly-brings-the-spotlight-on-leia-she-is-just-as-important-as-luke-101653651962936.html)

Comment: I wouldn't take the show description as an in-universe fact. There's no indication that Obi-wan paid any attention to Leia until Bail contacted him (and then, as you indicate, only begrudgingly).